# Using expo-modules with 3rd party local xcframework (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-native-module, expo-module

I'm trying to build a react-native wrapper module for the official Spotify SDK, using expo-modules. I've added the SDK in my `.podspec` file using `s.vendored_frameworks`. Example app's project pre-build works fine, but the framework's header files do not get copied, and while building the app for the Simulator, I get this error:

```
❌  (/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/expospotifyexample-ayfjxgjzbhoakacqvfpiaawhvpwz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExpoSpotify/ExpoSpotify-umbrella.h:13:9)

  11 | #endif
  12 | 
> 13 | #import "SpotifyAppRemote.h"
     |         ^ 'SpotifyAppRemote.h' file not found
  14 | #import "SpotifyiOS.h"
  15 | #import "SPTAppRemote.h"
  16 | #import "SPTAppRemoteAlbum.h"
```

It works fine if I manually copy SDK's header files to the path from the error.

my folder structure (just the important bits):

```
├─ example/
│  ├─ ios/
│  │  ├─ Pods/
│  │  │  ├─ Headers/
│  │  │  │  ├─ Public/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ ExpoSpotify/
│  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ ExpoSpotify.modulemap
│  │  │  │  │  │  ├─ ExpoSpotify-umbrella.h
├─ ios/
│  ├─ SpotifyiOS.xcframework/
│  │  ├─ ios-arm64_armv7/
│  │  │  ├─ SpotifyiOS.framework/
│  │  │  │  ├─ Headers/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ SpotifyAppRemote.h
│  │  │  │  ├─ Modules/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ module.modulemap
│  │  ├─ ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/
│  │  │  ├─ SpotifyiOS.framework/
│  │  │  │  ├─ Headers/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ SpotifyAppRemote.h
│  │  │  │  ├─ Modules/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ module.modulemap
│  │  ├─ Info.plist
│  ├─ ExpoSpotify.podspec
│  ├─ ExpoSpotifyModule.swift
```

my .podspec file:

```
require 'json'

package = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, '..', 'package.json')))

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name           = 'ExpoSpotify'
  s.version        = package['version']
  s.summary        = package['description']
  s.description    = package['description']
  s.license        = package['license']
  s.author         = package['author']
  s.homepage       = package['homepage']
  s.platform       = :ios, '13.0'
  s.swift_version  = '5.4'
  s.source         = { git: 'https://github.com/' }
  s.static_framework = true

  s.dependency 'ExpoModulesCore'

  # Swift/Objective-C compatibility
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES',
    'SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE' => 'wholemodule',
  }

  s.preserve_paths = "ExpoSpotify/SpotifyiOS.xcframework/**/*"
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'ExpoSpotify/SpotifyiOS.xcframework'
  s.source_files = "**/*.{h,m,swift}", 'ExpoSpotify/SpotifyiOS.xcframework/**/Headers/*.{h,m}'
end
```

One thing I've noticed. In the example apps `example/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/ExpoSpotify-umbrella.h` file, the imports are doubled and flat:

```
#import "SpotifyAppRemote.h"
... other headers
#import "SpotifyAppRemote.h"
... other headers
```

but when I add to the .podspec the path to framework's modulemap:

`s.header_mappings_dir = 'ExpoSpotify/ios/SpotifyiOS.xcframework/**/Modules'`

then imports are relative (but wrong path)

```
#import "../../../../../SpotifyiOS.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/SpotifyiOS.framework/Headers/SpotifyAppRemote.h"
#import "../../../../../SpotifyiOS.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/SpotifyiOS.framework/Headers/SpotifyAppRemote.h"
```

if it ditch the ExpoSpotify in the path

```
s.preserve_paths = "SpotifyiOS.xcframework/**/*"
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'SpotifyiOS.xcframework'
  s.source_files = "**/*.{h,m,swift}", 'SpotifyiOS.xcframework/**/Headers/*.{h,m}'
  s.header_mappings_dir = 'SpotifyiOS.xcframework/**/Modules'
```

The import path is shorter (still wrong):

```
#import "../../ios-arm64_armv7/SpotifyiOS.framework/Headers/SpotifyAppRemote.h"
#import "../../ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/SpotifyiOS.framework/Headers/SpotifyAppRemote.h"
```

I'm using MacBook with M2 processor, macOS Ventura (13.3.1), latest Xcode, Cocoapods 1.12.0.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? trying to work on something similar!